# MIS complexity in cubic triangle-free graphs

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, np-complete, reductions

The question [Complexity of Independent Set on Triangle-Free Planar Cubic Graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33171/complexity-of-independent-set-on-triangle-free-planar-cubic-graphs) asks for the complexity of the independent set problem in triangle-free planar cubic graphs. In the statement of the question [Independent set on cubic triangle-free graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9572/independent-set-on-cubic-triangle-free-graphs), it is claimed that a more general problem - maximum independent set in triangle-free cubic graphs (not necessarily planar) - is NP-complete. Could you please provide a reference to the paper for that result?

(Note that the answer to the first of the mentioned questions provides a paper where MIS is shown to be NP-hard in triangle-free planar graphs with vertices of degree <= 3, and I am asking for 3-regular graphs.)

**Update**: There has appeared a new answer in there since, and it addresses this question as well. The note ["NP-complete problems on a 3-connected cubic planar graph and their applications" by Ryuhei Uehara](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/%7Euehara/pdf/triangle.pdf) contains a proof that MIS is NP-complete for cubic, planar, and 3-connected graphs of girth greater than 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper "The Vertex-Disjoint Triangles Problem" (http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/10692760_3) by Guruswami et al. has the proof of its NP-completeness as Theorem 3.

**Update**: As stated in a more recent answer to [Complexity of Independent Set on Triangle-Free Planar Cubic Graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33171/complexity-of-independent-set-on-triangle-free-planar-cubic-graphs), there is a note ["NP-complete problems on a 3-connected cubic planar graph and their applications" by Ryuhei Uehara](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/%7Euehara/pdf/triangle.pdf) that contains a proof that MIS is NP-complete for cubic, planar, and 3-connected graphs of girth greater than 3.